# Never underestimate thermodynamics (especially when it relates to gravity)

Tags: thermodynamics, gravity, ads-cft

In the [review paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.04078) by Subir Sachdev, the low-temperature effective action of charged SYK models has been derived using holography.
In section 4, arguments of thermodynamics are used to derive the action for the phase mode corresponding to U(1) charge fluctuations. 
With some manipulation one can write (Eq.(4.12) of the Ref):
\begin{equation}
  K \left[\left( \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial T}\right)_Q \right]^2
=
\left( \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial T^2}\right)_Q-\left( \frac{\partial^2 \Omega}{\partial T^2}\right)_\mu
\end{equation}

with compressibility $K = (\partial Q/\partial \mu)_T$. The above relation can be seen as a map between temperature derivatives of the granpotential $\Omega$ and free energy $F$.

In the author's own words:

> *At order $T^2$, such an analysis amounts to replacing $(\partial\mu/\partial T)_Q$ by the difference in the chemical potential between the two approaches divided by $T$. So we need to take the difference between the chemical potential in the fixed $\mu$ case [...] from that in the fixed $Q$ case.*

I would naively think that at $T^2$ we could just replace $(\partial\mu/\partial T)_Q$ by $\frac{\mu(T)-\mu(T=0)}{T}$ but I am sure I am missing something obvious. 
Any hint?